# include view after extracting data

Tags: php, templates, html-rendering

I have two functions `loadView()` and `render()` in my view class.

```
public function loadView($view){
        if(file_exists(APP.'view/'.$view)){
            require(APP.'view/'.$view);
        }
        else{
            die(APP.'view/'.$view.' not found.');
        }
    }

public function render($view,$data = array()){
        if(!empty($data)){
            extract($data);
            ob_start();
            //$this->loadView($view);  -------------- not woriking
            require(APP.'view/'.$view);        ------ working
            $this->output = ob_get_clean();

            echo $this->output;
        }
    }
```

Whenever I call the `loadview` function from the `render` its not working. But if I `include` the view file directly after extracting data, it works. Anybody can tell me Why is this happening here or any solution ?

Comment: note: `require` is a language construct (not a function) and does not require parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

This will not work, because `require()` includes the required code in the place of the `require()` statement and in the scope of that location. In this case, the scope is the `loadView()` method. Within that method scope the extracted variables from the `render()` method are not available.

Instead of finding a solution for that, I would encourage you to use a template engine for your views like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). This is standard practice in MVC frameworks. Then, you could do something like this:

```
public function render($view,$data = array()){
    $template = $twig->loadTemplate($view);
    echo $template->render($data);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that twig is "standard practice" for MVC frameworks. Twig is one of many template engines which is one option for one component of the presentation layer

Comment: My point is exactly yours: a template engine is standard practice in many frameworks. Thus the word 'like' in my statement.